# Hadoop 2.6 with MongoDB Connector (1.3.1)?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

I'm using Hadoop 2.6 and MongoDB 2.4.12.
Is possible using Hadoop 2.6 with  MongoDB Connector for Hadoop (1.3.1) ?

I'm reading on the official website the MongoDB Connector supports Hadoop versions 0.23, 1.0, 1.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4. 
Are there issues when using Hadoop v 2.6 ?
Thank you in advance!